# Django template {%url %} link formatting

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I use {% url %} method to create link
`{% url application_name:staff:url.linkfield %}`
it is producing error in the console i.e.

```
raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ':staff:url.linkfield' from 'application_name:staff:url.linkfield'
```

This is my url.py

```
app_name="application_name"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^staff/",include('application_name.staff_url', namespace='staff')),
    url(r"^customer/",include('application_name.customer_url', namespace='customer')),
]
```

my staff_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="staff"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^customers/",views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r"^orders/$", views.orders, name='orders'),
    url(r"^payments/$", views.payments, name='payments'),
]
```

my customer_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="customer"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^items/",views.items, name='items'),
    url(r"^checkout/$", views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    url(r"^make_payment/$", views.make_payment, name='make_payment'),
]
```

staf url would be `staff/orders` or `staff/payments`
customer urls would be `customer/items` or `customer/checkout` etc

Please what can i do

**Update**

```
{% for url in links %}
    {% url.linkfield %}
{%endfor%}
```

That is what url.linkfield is for

**Update to include view**

```
        View
        
staffLink=[
                    {'linkfield':"customers", 'name':"Customers",'slug':"staff"},
                    {'linkfield':"orders", 'name':"Orders",'slug':"staff"},
                    {'linkfield':"payments", 'name':"payments",'slug':"staff"}]
                    
links=staffLink
request.session['links']= links

context_dict = {'links':links} 
                
        html template
            
{% for link in request.session.links %}
    <a href="{% url  application_name:staff: link.linkfield as the_url %}" class="nav-link">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what is url.linkfield?

Comment: @tahamaatof check update

Comment: please add your models and views , so it is easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

so  this is your main url:

```
urlpatterns=[
  url(r"^staff/",include('application_name.staff_url', namespace='staff')),
  url(r"^customer/",include('application_name.customer_url', namespace='customer')),
```

]

you do not need an app_name for the main url.

to rewrite:

```
{% url application_name:staff:url.linkfield %}
```

would be

```
{% url 'staff:customers' %} or
{% url 'staff:orders' %} or
{% url 'staff:payments' %}
```

or the other urls

```
{% url 'staff:customers' %} or
{% url 'customer:checkout' %} or
{% url 'customer:make_payment' %}
```

if links is a result of a queryset, and you use it as context,

and linkfield is a field of that model you used to query, then

```
{% for url in links %}
  {{ url.linkfield }}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Please what about other application which exist, if they have the same link e.g. application_name is the first, software_model is second application. How can I make use of these applications

Comment: I just tried your answer {%  staff:url.linkfield %}. This produced an error.        `raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ':url.linkfield' from 'staff:url.linkfield'`

Comment: i did not  give you this {% staff:url.linkfield %} as answer, please read carefully and if possible reformulate your question and provide views, and models,

Comment: I am doing a loop on the llinks which is the reason why I made use of {% staff:url.linkfield %}. Those links would be coming from a loop which would then fill it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try please this syntax
`{% url 'some-url-name' arg arg2 as the_url %}`

Comment: please can u elucidate your answer. Can u make it more clear'er'

Comment: I tried what your answer `{% url application_name staff url.linkfield as the_url %}`.  Please note that I included the spaces this did not produce any error in the console but all the links in the webpage were all `application_name/staff` the real url were not included which is it should have been `application_name/staff/orders` etc

Comment: It seems as if it displayed the url of the home page which is `someurl/application_name/staff`